# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient

After updating my code to HttpClient I can't get filter() to work with the response. I keep getting Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object':

**TS**:

```
liqOnChange(selection): void  {
        this.http.get(this.json_liq).subscribe(res => {
            this.arr = res.filter(
                res => res.id == selection.target.value);
        });
}
```

Comment: Filter is an array method. Is `res` an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filter` is an array method which cannot be used for objects in your case `res`.

First check if `res` is an array.

```
if(Array.isArray(res)){
   this.arr = res.filter(
                res => res.id == selection.target.value);
}
```

Or set type to `res` as `(res: Array<any>)`

If your api is returning an object, in most cases it should be, you can't use `filter` method here, you should be using it for an array inside `res` object.

Comment: The problem came from the API, thanks for pointing that out. I was sure that I was getting an array but after checking like u said and setting the type to array without success I realized that I was getting an object with an array inside.

Comment: @prevox no problem

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
this.http.get(this.json_liq).subscribe(res => {
```

to this:

```
this.http.get(this.json_liq).subscribe((res: any) => {
```

or better yet to this:

```
 this.http.get(this.json_liq).subscribe((res: Array<any>) => {
```

and you should be able to bypass your typechecking error at the compiler.

Here is some more info from the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript,
>   allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during
>   compilation. You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it
>   does in other languages. But variables of type Object only allow you
>   to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on
>   them, even ones that actually exist:

```
let notSure: any = 4;
notSure.ifItExists(); // okay, ifItExists might exist at runtime
notSure.toFixed(); // okay, toFixed exists (but the compiler doesn't check)

let prettySure: Object = 4;
prettySure.toFixed(); // Error: Property 'toFixed' doesn't exist on type 'Object'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your res in not array please check type of res, if it is array then filter method work.

Answer (score 1):

Either the object is null or it is not an array 
try to check if the object is not null and is an array with 
 `if(res != null && Array.isArray(res))`